# Problema ao cadastrar usuario na lista

Tags: java

Estou tentando cadastrar os usuários e colocar na lista. 
Inicialmente tentei apenas cadastrar e testar com o print. (Mesmo assim indica erros) Alguém sabe por que não está dando certo?
Os erros são:

> cannot find symbol no cliente.setNome(scanner.nextLine());

e

> Constructor Clientes in class Clientes cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: java.lang.String
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

Código:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CadastraUsuarios {

    public void menu(){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Clientes> listaDeUsuarios = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
     Clientes cliente = new Clientes();      
    int op = 0;


    char opcao;

    System.out.printf("MENU DE ESCOLHAS");
    System.out.printf("A- CADASTRAR CLIENTE");
    System.out.printf("B- INSERIR O CADASTRO DE UM NOVO TIPO DE SEGURO");
    System.out.printf("C- LISTAR TODOS OS SEGUROS CADASTRADOS");
    System.out.printf("D- LISTAR TODOS OS CLIENTES CADASTRADOS");
    System.out.printf("E- LISTAR OS SEGUROS CADASTRADOS PARA UM DETERMINADO CLIENTE");
    System.out.printf("F- BUSCAR INFORMAÇÕES DE UM SEGURO PELO NÚMERO DE ÁPOLICE");
    System.out.printf("S- SAIR");

    switch(opcao){
        case 'a': System.out.printf("Cadastro de Cliente:");

        //cadastrar clientes
        break;
        case 'b': System.out.printf("");
        //inserir o cadastro de um novo tipo de seguro
        break;
        case 'c' : System.out.printf("");
        //listar todos os seguros cadastrados

        break;
        case 'd' : System.out.printf("");
        //listar todos os clientes cadastrados

        break;
        case 'e' : System.out.printf("");
        //listar os seguros cadastrados para um determinado cliente

        break;
        case 'f' : System.out.printf("");
        //buscar as informações de um seguro pelo número de apólice

        break;
        case 's' : System.out.printf("saindo do programa");
        //sair do programa

        break;



    }
    }

    public  void cadastro(){
    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao sistema de cadastros de usuários");
    System.out.println("Digite o nome do usuário");
    cliente.setNome(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println(cliente.getNome());
    }
    }
```

Classe Cliente:

```
 public class Clientes
 {
 String nome; 
 String cpf; 
 String data_de_nascimento;
 String endereco;

 public Clientes(String nome)
 {
    this.nome = nome ;
    System.out.println("Construtor Funcionario");
}
    public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getNome()
{
    return nome;
}

}
```

Comment: que erros são indicados?

Comment: realmente, qual é o erro?

Comment: cannot find symbol no cliente.setNome(scanner.nextLine());
e Constructor Clientes in class Clientes cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.lang.String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variavel entrada esta dentro do escopo `CadastraUsuarios.menu`:

```
CadastraUsuarios {

    public void menu(){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Não tem como ter acesso em um escopo totalmente diferente que no caso é `CadastraUsuarios.cadastro`:

> Além de que você trocou o nome `entrada` por `scanner`

```
public  void cadastro(){
System.out.println("Bem vindo ao sistema de cadastros de usuários");
System.out.println("Digite o nome do usuário");
cliente.setNome(scanner.nextLine());
System.out.println(cliente.getNome());
}
```

O correto seria algo como:

```
public class CadastraUsuarios
{
    Scanner entrada;

    public void menu()
    {
       entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
       ...
    }

    public  void cadastro(){
       ...
       cliente.setNome(entrada.nextLine());
       ...
    }
```

Então estará acessível "no escopo" da classe toda

Outro problema citado pelo [@LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq) é que a classe Clientes espera no construtor por uma `String`:

```
public Clientes(String nome)
 {
    this.nome = nome ;
    System.out.println("Construtor Funcionario");
}
```

Mas ao instanciar você não passou nada:

```
ArrayList<Clientes> listaDeUsuarios = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
Clientes cliente = new Clientes();  //AQUI
```

Pelo `public Clientes(String nome)` é esperado que passe uma `String`, como não passou nada ocasiona o erro:

> cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String found: no arguments reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length